# What kind of URL changes do not cause a resource refetch?

Tags: http, url, browser, fragment-identifier

In Chrome 61,

- When I am on`https://example.com/#h0` and change the url (in the address bar or by manipulating `location.href`) to `https://example.com/`, then the page is reloaded, i.e. an HTTP request is made.
- A reverse operation, i.e. changing `/` to `/#h0`, doesn't cause a page reload.
- Similarly, changing the fragment identifier also doesn't cause a page reload.

Is there any formal specification on which fragment identifier changes cause a page reload and which don't? Or is it up to the browser's implementation?

I'm not surprised that changes of fragment-identifier just jump to the element with the provided id. I was initially surprised that removing the fragment identifier causes a page reload.